# rxjs Run some action and return a different Type

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

In TypeScript psuedocode, I've got some modal pop-up that returns an `Observable<ModalOption>`

```
class ModalOption {
    Yes,
    No
}
```

Now if they choose `Yes`, I want to run some authentication action that will return `Observable<bool>` depending on whether they successfully logged in.

How would I structure my rxjs so that I can go from `Observable<ModalOption>`, run my authentication then ultimately return `Observable<bool>` on authentication success/failure?

Comment: Kindly provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do for example this:

```
const source: Observable<ModalOption> = ...;

source
  .map<ModalOption, boolean>(...)
  .subscribe((val: boolean) => {});
```